# Maya + Python: Move pivot to bottom of bounding box

Tags: python, maya

How can I move just the pivot of the selected node to the bottom of the bounding box?

```
# Move the pivot for each selected not to it's center then bottom

import maya.cmds as cmds

curSel = cmds.ls(long = True, selection = True, type = 'dagNode')

for n in curSel:
    bbox = cmds.exactWorldBoundingBox(n)

    cmds.xform(n, cp=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bbox` is a 6-element list of *XYZ min* and *XYZ max*: `[xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax]`. If you want the pivot point to be the bottom center, you'll want the average X, minimum Y, and average Z:

```
bbox = cmds.exactWorldBoundingBox(n)
bottom = [(bbox[0] + bbox[3])/2, bbox[1], (bbox[2] + bbox[5])/2]
cmds.xform(n, piv=bottom, ws=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking confused when trying to solve this using the help doc.

Comment: Does this need to have world space tag?

Comment: Yeah, I put the ws tag in there and it worked properly. Otherwise it appears to be local to the object space.